Silkscreen Advice
My former career back in the 80s and 90s was spent as a graphic designer and I've recently designed some graphics that I would like to apply to some t-shirts but after running into some significant quality issues using online vendors to reproduce my artwork on t-shirts, I've starting thinking about doing it myself in order to control the quality of the work I'm trying to  produce.
Can anyone share any recommendations, experience or direction regarding getting started in this endevour?
I've done some screen-printing in the past on a very small scale and understand the basics as well.
PS: This is a 3-color job...
Thanks in advance..

This really isn't a good question for Stack Exchange sites (like this one.) It is exceptionally subjective. One person's recommendation may be completely different than another's - and you'd be hard pressed to pick a definitive answer. You should do some more research rather than asking for open-ended directions.

Keep your workspace clean?... You need to be more specific. About the craft? About preparing the artwork?

At its most basic, screen printing can be extremely simple. You need a screen, photographic emulsion, a way to print your artwork in black onto a transparency, sunlight for the exposure, a squeegee and ink, and some heating method to cure the ink. As for getting 3 colours to register (particularly if they are close to each other), that's going to be quite difficult without a dedicated machine to hold the screens to register all of the colours accurately.

An oversized comment
"I am going to make some 3-color screen prints of my own designs in my home. How should I start?"
We cannot give any proper list what to do because most of us do not know what your art and quality norms (for example sizes of the details, color placement accuracy and repeatability) require and what your exact situation allows. In addition only few of us have some serious experience of practical screen printing procedures. We draw, we make layouts and we process images.
Ats & Crafts Stack Exchange is a little better site for your problem. Someone there may know a good source for general information for a starter who want to utilize currently available materials. Show there a piece of the wanted result, too!
